# Pandas: how to convert dataframe with duplicate index values to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I have a DataFrame `df_test` as follows:

```
a   b   c
5   7   1
6   7   0
15  17  1
16  17  0
```

### Question

I am trying to create a dictionary from this dataframe with column b as index. Please note that values in column `b` are repeated. When I created the dictionary using the code given below, it just shows the last row as the output. How to create a dictionary to include all the information provided in the dataframe.

**Tested code**

Following is the code:

```
df_test.set_index('b', inplace=True)
df_test.T.to_dict(orient="list")
```

**Output**

```
{7: [6, 0], 17: [16, 0]}
```

**Desired output**

The output should include all the rows corresponding to each of the keys, not just the last row. Something similar to, but not restricted to, the output shown below:

```
{7: [[5, 1],[6, 0]], 17: [[15, 1],[16, 0]]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for processing all columns without `b` in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) in lambda function for convert to nested lists and then to dictionary:

```
d = df_test.set_index('b').groupby('b').apply(lambda x : x.to_numpy().tolist()).to_dict()
print (d)
{7: [[5, 1], [6, 0]], 17: [[15, 1], [16, 0]]}
```

Comment: how could I preserve `colnames`?