# Convert `DataFrame.groupby()` into dictionary (and then reverse it)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Say I have the following `DataFrame()` where I have repeated observations per individual (column `id_ind`). Hence, first two rows belong the first individual, the third and fourth rows belong to the second individual, and so forth...

```
import pandas as pd
X =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x1_1': {0: -0.1766214634108258, 1: 1.645852185286492, 2: -0.13348860101031038, 3: 1.9681043689968933, 4: -1.7004428240831382, 5: 1.4580091413853749, 6: 0.06504113741068565, 7: -1.2168493676768384, 8: -0.3071304478616376, 9: 0.07121332925591593}, 'x1_2': {0: -2.4207773498298844, 1: -1.0828751040719462, 2: 2.73533787008624, 3: 1.5979611987152071, 4: 0.08835542172064115, 5: 1.2209786277076156, 6: -0.44205979195950784, 7: -0.692872860268244, 8: 0.0375521181289943, 9: 0.4656030062266639}, 'x1_3': {0: -1.548320898226322, 1: 0.8457342014424675, 2: -0.21250514722879738, 3: 0.5292389938329516, 4: -2.593946520223666, 5: -0.6188958526077123, 6: 1.6949245117526974, 7: -1.0271341091035742, 8: 0.637561891142571, 9: -0.7717170035055559}, 'x2_1': {0: 0.3797245517345564, 1: -2.2364391598508835, 2: 0.6205947900678905, 3: 0.6623865847688559, 4: 1.562036259999875, 5: -0.13081282910947759, 6: 0.03914373833251773, 7: -0.995761652421108, 8: 1.0649494418154162, 9: 1.3744782478849122}, 'x2_2': {0: -0.5052556836786106, 1: 1.1464291788297152, 2: -0.5662380273138174, 3: 0.6875729143723538, 4: 0.04653136473130827, 5: -0.012885303852347407, 6: 1.5893672346098884, 7: 0.5464286050059511, 8: -0.10430829457707284, 9: -0.5441755265313813}, 'x2_3': {0: -0.9762973303149007, 1: -0.983731467806563, 2: 1.465827578266328, 3: 0.5325950414202745, 4: -1.4452121324204903, 5: 0.8148816373643869, 6: 0.470791989780882, 7: -0.17951636294180473, 8: 0.7351814781280054, 9: -0.28776723200679066}, 'x3_1': {0: 0.12751822396637064, 1: -0.21926633684030983, 2: 0.15758799357206943, 3: 0.5885412224632464, 4: 0.11916562911189271, 5: -1.6436210334529249, 6: -0.12444368631987467, 7: 1.4618564171802453, 8: 0.6847234328916137, 9: -0.23177118858569187}, 'x3_2': {0: -0.6452955690715819, 1: 1.052094761527654, 2: 0.20190339195326157, 3: 0.6839430295237913, 4: -0.2607691613858866, 5: 0.3315513026670213, 6: 0.015901139336566113, 7: 0.15243420084881903, 8: -0.7604225072161022, 9: -0.4387652927008854}, 'x3_3': {0: -1.067058994377549, 1: 0.8026914180717286, 2: -1.9868531745912268, 3: -0.5057770735303253, 4: -1.6589569342151713, 5: 0.358172252880764, 6: 1.9238983803281329, 7: 2.2518318810978246, 8: -1.2781475121874357, 9: -0.7103081175166167}})
Y = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'CHOICE': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 2.0, 9: 2.0}})
Z = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'z1': {0: 2.4196730570917233, 1: 2.4196730570917233, 2: 2.822802255159467, 3: 2.822802255159467, 4: 2.073171091633643, 5: 2.073171091633643, 6: 2.044165101485163, 7: 2.044165101485163, 8: 2.4001241292606275, 9: 2.4001241292606275}, 'z2': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 'z3': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 3.0, 9: 3.0}})
id = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id_choice': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0, 8: 9.0, 9: 10.0}, 'id_ind': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 3.0, 6: 4.0, 7: 4.0, 8: 5.0, 9: 5.0}} )
# Create a dataframe with all the data 
data = pd.concat([id, X, Z, Y], axis=1)
print(data.head(4))

#    id_choice  id_ind      x1_1      x1_2      x1_3      x2_1      x2_2  \
# 0        1.0     1.0 -0.176621 -2.420777 -1.548321  0.379725 -0.505256   
# 1        2.0     1.0  1.645852 -1.082875  0.845734 -2.236439  1.146429   
# 2        3.0     2.0 -0.133489  2.735338 -0.212505  0.620595 -0.566238   
# 3        4.0     2.0  1.968104  1.597961  0.529239  0.662387  0.687573   
# 
#        x2_3      x3_1      x3_2      x3_3        z1   z2   z3  CHOICE  
# 0 -0.976297  0.127518 -0.645296 -1.067059  2.419673  0.0  1.0     1.0  
# 1 -0.983731 -0.219266  1.052095  0.802691  2.419673  0.0  1.0     1.0  
# 2  1.465828  0.157588  0.201903 -1.986853  2.822802  0.0  1.0     2.0  
# 3  0.532595  0.588541  0.683943 -0.505777  2.822802  0.0  1.0     2.0
```

---

I want to perform two operations.

1. First, I want to convert the DataFrame `data` into a dictionary of `DataFrame()`s where the keys are the number of individuals (in this particular case, numbers ranging from `1.0` to `5.0`.). I've done this below as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640305/pandas-how-to-convert-dataframe-with-duplicate-index-values-to-a-dictionary). Unfortunately, I am getting a dictionary of numpy values and not a dictionary of `DataFrame()`s.

```
# Create a dictionary with the data for each individual
data_dict = data.set_index('id_ind').groupby('id_ind').apply(lambda x : x.to_numpy().tolist()).to_dict()
print(data_dict.keys())
# dict_keys([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
print(data_dict[1.0])
#[[1.0, -0.1766214634108258, -2.4207773498298844, -1.548320898226322, 0.3797245517345564, -0.5052556836786106, -0.9762973303149007, 0.12751822396637064, -0.6452955690715819, -1.067058994377549, 2.4196730570917233, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.645852185286492, -1.0828751040719462, 0.8457342014424675, -2.2364391598508835, 1.1464291788297152, -0.983731467806563, -0.21926633684030983, 1.052094761527654, 0.8026914180717286, 2.4196730570917233, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

2. Second, I want to recover the original DataFrame `data` reversing the previous operation. The naive approach is as follows. However, it is, of course, not producing the expected result.

```
# Naive approach
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient='index') 
print(res)
#   0   1
#1.0    [1.0, -0.1766214634108258, -2.4207773498298844...   [2.0, 1.645852185286492, -1.0828751040719462, ...
#2.0    [3.0, -0.13348860101031038, 2.73533787008624, ...   [4.0, 1.9681043689968933, 1.5979611987152071, ...
#3.0    [5.0, -1.7004428240831382, 0.08835542172064115...   [6.0, 1.4580091413853749, 1.2209786277076156, ...
#4.0    [7.0, 0.06504113741068565, -0.4420597919595078...   [8.0, -1.2168493676768384, -0.692872860268244,...
#5.0    [9.0, -0.3071304478616376, 0.0375521181289943,...   [10.0, 0.07121332925591593, 0.4656030062266639...
```

Comment: I don't understand the "*Suggestions about how to keep them in place are also welcome.*", what would the dictionary with column names look like?

Comment: thank you for your comment, @mozway. You are right; it doesn't make sense. What I just realized is that what I want is to have a dictionary of `DataFrames`, so I can reverse the operation afterward more easily. I will edit my question.

Comment: Then `dict(list(data.groupby('id_choice')))`?

Comment: Exactly! Thank you for that. However, `dict(list(data.groupby('id_ind')))` to group by individuals.

Comment: then reversing the operation it is simply `res = pd.concat(data_dict, axis=0)`

Comment: Exactly, you got it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This solution was inspired by [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) comments.

```
# Create a dictionary with the data for each individual
data_dict = dict(list(data.groupby('id_ind')))
# Convert the dictionary into a dataframe
res = pd.concat(data_dict, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(res.head(4))
#   id_choice  id_ind      x1_1      x1_2      x1_3      x2_1      x2_2  \
#0        1.0     1.0 -0.176621 -2.420777 -1.548321  0.379725 -0.505256   
#1        2.0     1.0  1.645852 -1.082875  0.845734 -2.236439  1.146429   
#2        3.0     2.0 -0.133489  2.735338 -0.212505  0.620595 -0.566238   
#3        4.0     2.0  1.968104  1.597961  0.529239  0.662387  0.687573   
#
#       x2_3      x3_1      x3_2      x3_3        z1   z2   z3  CHOICE  
#0 -0.976297  0.127518 -0.645296 -1.067059  2.419673  0.0  1.0     1.0  
#1 -0.983731 -0.219266  1.052095  0.802691  2.419673  0.0  1.0     1.0  
#2  1.465828  0.157588  0.201903 -1.986853  2.822802  0.0  1.0     2.0  
#3  0.532595  0.588541  0.683943 -0.505777  2.822802  0.0  1.0     2.0
```